# How to make a chat screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, layout, chat

[This is my desired chat output screen]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUrQA.jpg
I am working with flutter. I am trying to make a chat screen which shown in the picture. But I have some problem and cause some overflow issues. In a simple way, I use just text fields, and some basic widgets.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code and the error output that you are getting.